# how to make a chrome extension clickable

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

after reading the tutorials I still can't make my extension to work after clicking on it, it starts working as soon as the page loaded.

Here is my manifest.

```c
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "My extension",
  "description": "This extension bla bla.",
  "version": "3.0",

  "permissions": [
    "tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*"
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
  },

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*"],
      "js": ["make_changes.js"]
    }
    ],
    "background": {
    "scripts": ["make_changes.js"],
    "persistent": false
  }

}
```

and here is my make_changes.js:

```c
var oldSource = document.documentElement.innerHTML;

document.body.innerHTML = Make_change(oldSource);


function Make_change(source){
 ...
}
```

I've also got the background.HTML file, but it works without it. It seems that it is not correct:

```c
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "make_changes.js"});
```

Comment: the background.html file is not registered in manifest file, cause even when I register it, it doesn't change anything or even worse my extension doesn't work at all.

Comment: I dont think i understand what you are asking...what are you trying to make clickable? I can see you are trying to manipulate the DOM but thats about it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a listener for the browser action `onClicked` event:

http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction.html#event-onClicked

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: "make_changes.js"});
});
```